# Opening multiple android tasks with the same root activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-task, android-recents, taskaffinity

I'm trying to start an intent with Main2Activity in a new (separate) task (i.e. separate back stack and separate instance in recents screen).
I realized that the way it should be done is adding the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` intent flags:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But this only works if I set (in the manifest) Main2Activity's  `android:taskAffinity` to other than the default (i.e. other than the current activity's task affinity).

The problem is that I want to be able to create another new task with the same activity more than once.

**Example:**

In the android Gmail app, you can click the "compose" button several times, and each time it creates a "new instance" of the composer.
I'd like to achieve the exact same behavior.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I think I just figured it out.

Replaced the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` and it seems to work fine.

note: this flag requires API level >= 21

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
```

You have to use only

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
```

because documents says that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` brings the old task in front if already started and create new task only if not running.